# ¿Cómo separar una variable en 2?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que dividir una variable que representa un RFC en dos, las letras estarían en una variable y los números en otra, como a continuación:

```
rfc = "JTGX280305";    
rfclet = "JTGX";
rfcnum = "280305";
```

Y después tengo que sumar los números, como a continuación:

```
sumrf = (2 + 8 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 5);
sumrf = ("18")
```

Comment: siempre hay 4 letras?

Comment: No se de javascript pero me imagino que tiene alguna funcion split en el cual puedes decirle que haga split en el primer numero otra solucion podria ser un regex para sacar los numeros, otra solucion posible seria ir recorriendo el string e ir concatenando los numeros

Comment: Eso supongo que con expresiones regulares y replace lo podrias conseguir, pero no veo lo que tu has hecho, simplemente nos estas asignando tu tarea, y aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos), lo siento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo asi, se puede mejorar obviamente, recorro la cadena hasta encontrar un numero,asi obtengo la posición para cortar la cadena, si siempre son 4 letras puedes eliminar el map y en la variable posicion le pones 4

```js
let rfc= "JTGX280305";
let position=0;
let arraytext=rfc.split("");
arraytext.map((a,index)=>{if(isNaN(a)){
position=index+1;
}});
let text=rfc.slice(0,position);
let num=rfc.slice(position);

let sum=num.split("").reduce((a,b)=>a+=parseFloat(b),0);



console.log(text)
console.log(num)
console.log(sum)
```